# How do I redirect different apps into a single domain with Nginx Ubuntu 16

Tags: server, nginx

I'm in charge of setting up a testing server in which all web applications should respond to a single domain, like this, for example:

dev.test.com/

What I want to do is to be able to pass the location of a different app and still be in the same domain, like so:

dev.test.com/thisapp

or

dev.test.com/differentapp

and I want to do it with Nginx, wich is the tool that I'm using. Problem is, I can only add them as diffent subdomains. I tried a few ways like putting all apps in one folder and trying to rename them all, with no luck. I have no idea how to achieve what I want and I already searched for weeks on end with nothing to help me achieve this. Some help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use can use the `location` tag for that. Edit your configuration file under `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled`, and add a location tag for each sub-site

```
server {
    location / {
        root /path/to/default;
    }

    location /thisapp/ {
        root /path/to/thisapp;
    }

    location /differentapp/ {
        root /path/to/differentapp;
    }
}
```

You can read more in the [nginx beginners guide](http://nginx.org/en/docs/beginners_guide.html#static)